# Почему американцев называют "пиндосами"?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Откуда вообще пошло это слово — "пиндос"? Я слышала, что, якобы, от Пелевина (но сама его не читала, потому что вообще не люблю модные книги).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пиндосы (пендосы, пиндосцы, пиндостанцы,  пиндосины) — типичные обитатели США. Соответственно, США в этом случае называется Пиндосия, Пиндостан или СШП (Соединенные Штаты Пиндосии). Слово происходит от греческого Πίνδος, в котором последнее время обозначало причерноморских греков (аналог фольклорных чукч в русском языке). [1], [2]
Первое появление слова «пиндосия» в медиа-пространстве отмечено в репортаже о русских десантниках из Косово, которые называли пиндосами военнослужащих американского миротворческого контингента (один из десантников мотивировал это так: «комнатные они какие-то»). В качестве лулза на одном из совещаний командующий российскими миротворцами в Косово генерал Евтухович сказал: «Товарищи офицеры, я вас прошу не называть пиндосов „пиндосами“, они на это очень обижаются» ...Нашел в интернете.

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, в Вики есть, пусть и не очень явно сформулированная, версия.

Степанов пишет, что при опросе в 1996—1999 гг. одесских моряков было установлено, что более половины из них не знают первоначального смысла слова «пиндос», а те, кто его знают, как правило, являются коренными одессситами и определяют два значения этого слова — 1) «грек (просторечное)» либо 2) «глупый, невоспитанный, нечистоплотный, никчёмный человек (грубое, брутальное)».

Второе значение вполне могло распространиться на американцев (будь то Косово или любая друга сфера соприкосновения) в период охлаждения отношений или на почве создания новой национальной идеи "Американцы - козлы!", каковой нас потчуют последние лет тридцать-сорок - за исключением небольшого периода перестройки и либерализации начала 90-х.

Странно, что, говоря об американских солдатах, никто не связал "пиндос" с Пентагон. 
Может, конечно, grumant что-то такое имел в виду своей цитатой "без конца и без начала" (хотя вряд ли), но уж до него я о такой версии не слышал.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно теории  Сергея Голубицкого, слово *пиндос* в современном разговорном языке как обозначение американских военнослужащих появилось после совместной работы в Косово российских и натовских войск, а в качестве одного из возможных источников его происхождения Голубицкий приводит информацию, что между мировыми войнами слово *пиндос* закрепилось в американском сленге и обозначало "всех низкорослых и черноволосых выходцев с Балкан (греков, румын, болгар) и юга Италии". По версии филолога, "российские солдаты в Косово сначала услышали слово „пиндос“ со стороны и только потом осознали, как оно замечательно ассоциируется с „вооруженным до зубов трусливым американским солдатом“.

[Сама статья](http://old.computerra.ru/offline/2004/559/35857/)

Comment: Ну это просто ерунда. Косовским событиям - лет десять максимум. А слову - много больше. Филолуха пороть розгами за портяночный национализм. Можно сколь угодно долго издеваться над якобы тупостью "мериканских" солдат, но при чем тут "трусость"?

Comment: @behemothus, "вооруженным до зубов трусливым американским солдатом“ - это цитата из интернета. Да и различия боевых уставов дают все основания считать американцев трусливыми, также как и русских солдат "crazy", хотя вопрос и не в этом.

Слово "пиндос" существует давно, но не по отношению к американцам, а к лошадям или грекам, причём слово до недавнего времени (как раз 90-е, 2000-е) было довольно редким. Перенос от причерноморских греков к американцам вряд ли имеет логическое обоснование.

Comment: >Перенос от причерноморских греков к американцам вряд ли имеет логическое обоснование.  
  
Безосновательно. У меня - не от греков, а по значению. 
Но здесь я больше даже не об этом, а о том, что филолух подменил значение "тупость" на трусость. Ни в каком контексте американцев в массе не ассоциируют с трусостью. Да и у пиндос/пендос в списке значений трусость идет где-то на задворках. 

Кстати, если мне память не изменяет, в Косове были войска НАТО, американцы составляли там какой-то совсем не астрономический процент с какого перепугу их всех объявили американскими?

Остальное в моем ответе.

Comment: Различия боевых уставов дают основания считать, что на западе больше ценят человеческую жизнь. Но не все понимают разницу между этим и трусостью. Особенно с психологией "бабы еще нарожают". Холопы такие холопы.

Comment: @SergZ. Различия боевых уставов позволяют говорить, что в натовских войсках основная задача сохранить конкретного солдата, а в российской - подразделение целиком. Поэтому, например, натовский пилот не будет снижаться, чтобы нанести удар точнее, даже если из-за этого может погибнуть куча собственной пехоты, а российский пилот так и сделает, несмотря на риск для собственной жизни. Единственный конфликт, когда две эти стратегии столкнулись с участием примерно равных армий стала война 08.08.08, победа была за Россией. Но здесь я это обсуждать не буду.

Answer (score 0):

На одном из наречий многоязычной бывшей Югославии "пиндос" (на сленге) означает "пингвин". Американские военнослужащие с горой своей амуниции , которую они должны таскать во время боевых действий на себе, похожи на пингвинов. Вот поэтому и "пиндос".

Comment: А есть какой-нибудь источник? На каком конкретно языке, какая амуниция, как прозвище военнослужащих могло перекинуться на весь народ, при чем тут вообще американцы и Югославия?

Answer (score 0):

Пиндос (ударение на «о») — опосредованное заимствование из древнегреческого. Этимологически слово происходит от названия хребта Пинд. Во времена расцвета Древней Греции слово «пиндос» (греч. Πίνδος) служило названием для жителей полисов, являвшихся членами Делосской лиги. Впоследствии «Πίνδος» стало одним из самоназваний греческих колонистов.                                           Утратив изначальный смысл, слово, тем не менее, достаточно прочно входило в армейский и уголовный жаргон 1950—1980-х гг., благодаря своей созвучности с рядом более ярких и более предметных ругательств, имевших широкое распространение в русской речи. Таковое изменение стало результатом адаптации сленгового слова без понимания его изначального смысла армейской и уголовной средой.

Comment: Послушайте, а источник не укажете? Много красивых слов - и ничего аргументированного. Ну каким образом "Пинд", пусть даже "опосредовано" оказаться в "армейском" языке? Чудивщина какая-то ей-богу...

Comment: Слово, утратив свой прежний смысл, обрело новый. И какой?